# Change video from 30 FPS to 1 FPS keeping duration and keeping audio in sync

Tags: ffmpeg, fps

Which FFMPEG command line could I use to:

- change FPS from 30 to 1 FPS
- keeping original video duration
- keeping original audio in sync
- if it goes - then without re-encoding
- **It MUST drop frames**

The video is a slide show of book texts that accompany audio. My idea is to reduce its size while keeping te possibility to seek, keeping still picture quality and keeping original audio quality.

Comment: "has answers here" - this is wrong. All the answers do not do what I want.

Comment: So what have you tried? What were the results? What commands come somewhere close but not quite what you want? There are several modifiable options at https://superuser.com/a/1291513/19943 which at least sounds close. You have to help people to help you, not expect them to do all your work for you

Comment: How about https://superuser.com/questions/1042576/reduce-video-frame-rate-without-dropping-useful-frames?rq=1 which seems like a possibility...